# Is there a eigenvalue equal to 0 if determinant is equal to 0?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

According to theorem the multiplication of all eigenvalues is equal to the determinant, so if one of them equals 0 the determinant is always 0. But is it true for the opposite statement? If determinant is equal to 0 is there for sure an eigenvalue equal to 0?

Comment: Can you post the theorem that you are talking about? I would assume that a proof by contradiction would be sufficient, but I need to see what we're working with.

Comment: The product of the n eigenvalues of A is the same as the determinant of A, where A is n x n matrix.

Comment: @dzi for *general* matrices? Or over the reals? Over complex numbers?

Comment: The theorem says that the two quantities are the same, therefore they are equal. Thus, if $det(A) = \lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n = 0$, then at least one $\lambda_i = 0$. I would assume that this theorem assumes the existence of eigenvalues.

Comment: @ClementC. Pardon me for not mentioning that as I didn't realise if it made a difference. The question is for general matrices.

Comment: @dzi Then what about cases where the characteristic polynomial cannot be factored?

Comment: @ClementC. Shouldn't i be able to tell if 0 is one of the factors even without factoring it?

Comment: Your question *assumes* existence of "all eigenvalues" -- this is not necessary, and not actually obvious to begin with. All you need is for 0 to be an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4):

If a square matrix $A$ has zero determinant, this implies that $A$ is not injective, i.e. the kernel is nonempty. So, there exists $v \neq 0$ such that $Av = 0 = 0\cdot v$. By definition, $v$ is an eigenvector for $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've heard of the characteristic polynomial. For a size$~n$ square matrix $A$ it is defined as $\det(XI_n-A)$, it is a monic polynomial of degree$~n$, and it has the property that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, in other words if $\det(\lambda I_n-A)=0$. Setting $\lambda=0$ in this statement, it says that $0$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\det(-A)=0$. It is not very hard to see that this is equivalent to $\det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the determinant of a matrix with real/complex entries is the product of its (complex) eigenvalues, so it has a matrix has a $0$ eigenvalue if and only if its determinant is $0$.

If you care about matrices with entries in a general field $F$, then as Clement points out the determinant will be the product of the eigenvalues which lie in the algebraic closure of $F$, and so once again a matrix has a $0$ eigenvalue if and only if its determinant is $0$.

Comment: What if the matrix is not diagonalizable? (Or more general statements about eigenvalues not existing) I.e., what about the general question from the OP: "can the determinant of a matrix be zero if 0 is not an eigenvalue" (without further assumptions)

Comment: Complex eigenvalues always exist, and their product is the determinant.

Comment: and all matrices are over real or complex numbers, *right*?

Comment: @ClementC. It doesn't matter whether the matrix is over the real or complex numbers, in either case the determinant of $M$ is the product of all the complex eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: You are missing the point. Not all things are subfields of the complex numbers. Not all scalars can be "seen" as complex. You can abstract concepts beyond $\mathbb C$, and your argument doesn't go through.

Comment: @Clement Can you be more explicit about what you're getting at? I think things can only really go wrong if you're allowing a matrix with entries that don't come from an integral domain. If people talk about the determinant in that context, then maybe that's worth mentioning. But I don't think diagonalizability is relevant.

Comment: Yes, they do. Consider a matrix over an arbitrary field, which is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Clement With a matrix over an arbitrary field, are there not eigenvalues in the algebraic closure whose product is the determinant?

Comment: @MarkS. "Yes, the determinant of a matrix is the product of its **(complex)** eigenvalues" (emphasis mine)

Comment: I only added "complex" because you asked if the matrix is not diagonalizable. But as you point out, a matrix always has eigenvalues in the algebraic closure of the field where the entries live, so my original answer without the word "complex" was perfectly fine. I have now clarified my answer.

Comment: @kccu Your original answer just assumed existence of eigenvalues. This is highly non trivial, so I asked you to clarify. Your answers didn't clarify that at all, in the contrary, so I downvoted.

Comment: Even with the clarification about complex eigenvalues, the answer is still wrong. The determinant is not necessarily equal to the product of all eigenvalues when there is an eigenvalue of multiplicity > 1. In this case you need to raise each eigenvalue to the power of its multiplicity in the product, but the correct notion of multiplicity here is a nontrivial issue for nondiagonalizable matrices.

Comment: This is what I like about James Yang's answer, it lets you bypass all these annoying details about the statement "the determinant is the product of eigenvalues".

Answer (score 0):

Fun, but overkill solution:

Zero determinant implies one of the singular values must be zero. By Weyl's Inequality, one of the eigenvalues must be zero.