# "Find the Change of Basis", "Represent a Transformation with respect to different Basis", miss conceptions in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a rough time figuring out what the exercise actually meant when they ask question like these. Let's consider the following exercise:

> Find the change of basis matrix for the following basis $A$ and $B$ for $R^2$
> $$
>     A=\begin{bmatrix}
>     2  \\
>     4  \\
>     \end{bmatrix},    
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     4  \\
>     5  \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
>     B=\begin{bmatrix}
>     0  \\
>     1  \\
>     \end{bmatrix},    
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     1  \\
>     0  \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$

for this exercise, I assumed it was asking me where the coordinates of $A$ would land using the coordinates from $B$, solved by using the formula $S = inverse of B * A$ 
`Question 1. Was my assumption correct or is there something more to the exercise?`

Now consider the following exercise:

> Consider the linear transformation $M$ with respect to the standard bases:
> $$
>     M=\begin{bmatrix}
>     2 & 1 \\
>     2 & 3
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> Represent this transformation with respect to the following two basis:
> $$
>     C=\begin{bmatrix}
>     0  \\
>     1  \\
>     \end{bmatrix},    
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     1  \\
>     0  \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
>     D=\begin{bmatrix}
>     2  \\
>     4  \\
>     \end{bmatrix},    
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     1  \\
>     3  \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$

`Question 2. What am I suppose to do differently from the previous exercise here?`

Comment: Please undelete the other post you made. Your question might be able to help other people and not just yourself. For example, here is a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192757/is-there-a-eigenvalue-equal-to-0-if-determinant-is-equal-to-0) to yours that has a lot of good answers.

Comment: Sure I will, I thought I had to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part I**

The change of basis matrix from $A$ to $B$ is the matrix $[I]_{A}^{B}$ whose columns are the vectors from the basis $A$ written in the basis $B$. Since $A = \{(2,4),(4,5)\}$ and $B = \{(0,1),(1,0)\}$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(2,4) = 4(0,1) + 2(1,0)\\\\
(4,5) = 5(0,1) + 4(1,0)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Therefore we have that
\begin{align*}
[I]_{A}^{B} =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5\\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

The matrix $[I]_{B}^{A} = ([I]_{A}^{B})^{-1}$.

**Part II**

Let us denote $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, $C = \{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and $D = \{(2,4),(1,3)\}$.

We know that any pair of matricial representations of a linear operator between finite-dimensional vector spaces are similar. More precisely, we have that $[T]_{\mathcal{B}} = [I]_{C}^{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{C}[I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{C}$ and $[T]_{\mathcal{B}} = [I]_{D}^{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{D}[I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{D}$. Now it remains to find the change of basis matrix for each case. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have only one question. When does one use the formula that involves around calculating the transpose and inverse of a matrix? It's still related to change of basis

Comment: The change of basis formula relates two different frames which one may choose to describe the vectors of a vector space. The formula $[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}$  in its turn results from the following argument:

Comment: $[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [IT]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = [TI]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = [T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} \Rightarrow [T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}$

Comment: Thus if we consider a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a pair of bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ of it, we have that

$$[I(v)]_{\mathcal{B}'} = [I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$$

Moreover, we do also have that

$$[T(v)]_{\mathcal{B}'} = [T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$$